# The dependency Twilio in project does not support framework DNXCore, Version=v5.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, twilio

I'm interested in figuring out how to use the Twilio API, and I am building an ASP.NET 5 application using the Twilio API with MVC6 (trying to follow [this tutorial](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/08/getting-started-with-asp-net-5-and-visual-studio-code-on-a-mac.html)). So far, I have created an empty ASP.NET 5 application, and I added "Twilio" to the dependencies in *project.json*. I get the following error:

`"The dependency Twilio 4.0.3 in project TwilioTest does not support framework DNXCore, Version v5.0"`

I notice that when I remove `"dnxcore50"` from `"frameworks"`, the error goes away.

I'm not sure what this means or how to approach it. I'm still pretty new to .NET and trying to wrap my head around how all of the pieces fit together. Does it mean that Twilio isn't compatible with DNXCore? Since all I want to do for now is learn how to use Twilio, could I essentially remove the `dnxcore50` framework from the project and continue working through building the app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Twillio NuGet package is dependent on the full .NET stack, which in project.json frameworks terms is DNX451.  What that means is, you can add the Twillio NuGet package and remove the DNXCORE50 reference and your project will run as expected and you will be able to use the Twillio API. As far as I know the only major drawback is that your ASP.NET Core project will no longer be cross platform as you are now dependent on the full .NET Framework stack which is only present in Windows.

In a nutshell, you should be fine unless you are planning to deploy to Linux/OSx. Hopefully as ASP.NET CORE becomes mainstream more 3rd party SDKs will be built to require only DNXCORE50 as a dependency.

Another option don't use the Twillio Libraries and code against their REST API. See documentation here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api.  But I wouldn't recommend this if you are deploying to a Windows environment.

Comment: if anyone is looking for working example code that uses the twilio rest api, I have code here that works with both dnxcore50 and dnx451 https://github.com/joeaudette/cloudscribe/blob/master/src/cloudscribe.Messaging.Sms/TwilioSmsSender.cs

Answer (score 1):

Twilio is [working on their .Net Standard (Core) library](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-csharp/tree/next-gen). In the meantime, I've published a .Net Core port of their library to unblock our current projects until we get the official update. Feel free to take it for a spin:

**Install [Twilio.NetCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Twilio.NetCore) from Nuget.**

And you can check out the source on [Github](https://github.com/ArashMotamedi/Twilio.NetCore).